# How does one lowercase regex replace?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

In VsVim I've tried `:s/(\w)/` +

- `\L1`
- `\l1`
- `\L$1`
- `\L$1\e`
- `\L$1\e`

how does one do a regex replace lowercase in [VsCode's vim](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim)?

Comment: does this help? http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html

Comment: nope, that's where I go whenever I have regex problems, this is specific to vim or vsvim

Answer (score 2):

In vim it would be:

```
:s/\(\w\)/\L\1/g
```

to replace every character on the line with its lowercase equivalent.
I don't use VsVim but if it emulates vim you should try escaping the parentheses.

**Update:** There are so many differences that my assumption that VSCodeVim emulates Vim is wrong, (or, at least, true only to some extent). In VSCodeVim you press `:` to open a command line box; there the expression:

```
s/(\w)/$1/g
```

replaces every alphanumeric character on the current line with itself (admittedly, not very useful). I coudn't find a way replace every alphanumeric character with its lowercase version. Notable differences from vim:

1. `:` does not go to the command line
2. parentheses do not need to be escaped
3. backreferences are written as `$1` instead of `\1`

Comment: I bet that's it, switching between .net regex, javascript regex, visual studio regex, vscode regex, and vsvim regex is certainly taxing.

Comment: that's not doing anything at all, no error, also no change.

Comment: It turns out I have VSCode installed, so I gave it a try. You need to omit the `:` (i.e., press it only once to open the command line) and don't have to escape parentheses. `\1` does not work, and needs to be written as `$1`. Apart from all these differences, lowercase backreference does not seem to be supported.

Comment: yeah, I can see how that wasn't clear, the `:` was the key I hit to bring up the command window, I didn't include it in the command line. I didn't escape parens, but either way it wouldn't work =/